# Starting Jupyterlab on boot in Linux

Tags: python, linux, conda, jupyter-lab

I have installed [JupyterLab](https://jupyter.org/install) on my Ubuntu 20.04 machine using [anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual).

I would like to start Jupyterlab on boot.

I CAN get Jupyterlab to run on boot by doing the following:

Create the file `/etc/systemd/system/jupyter.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=Jupyter Lab
[Service]
Type=simple
PIDFile=/run/jupyter.pid
ExecStart=/home/USERNAME/anaconda3/envs/jupyterlab/bin/jupyter lab
User=USERNAME
WorkingDirectory=/home/USERNAME/Documents
Restart=always
RestartSec=10
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

replacing USERNAME.

Then run the following commands:

```sh
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable jupyter.service
sudo systemctl restart jupyter.service
sudo systemctl status jupyter.service
```

HOWEVER, in a jupyter notebook, if I run the command

```sh
!python
```

I get my system python, not my conda environment python.

How can I start jupyterlab on boot, and still get `!commands` to work as expected?

Comment: This might be better scoped to SeverFault or SuperUser.

Comment: I have not tested with conda, but I do something similar with pyenv by wrapping it in `bash -i -c "cd relevant_dir; conda activate myenv; path/to/jupyter-lab > ~/jupyterlab.log  2>~jupyterlab.error"` (very rough draft based on what I am doing with pyenv).

Comment: But it might not work and you may need `nb_conda_kernels` or something like this.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @krassowski changing the `ExecStart` line to:

```
ExecStart=/bin/bash -i -c "conda activate jupyterlab;jupyter lab"
```

solved my problem.

i.e.:

```
[Unit]
Description=Jupyter Lab

[Service]
Type=simple
PIDFile=/run/jupyter.pid
ExecStart=/bin/bash -i -c "conda activate jupyterlab;jupyter lab"
User=USERNAME
WorkingDirectory=/home/USERNAME/Documents
Restart=always
RestartSec=10

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Solved my issue too ( Run Jupyterlab as a service under Anaconda )